# Remaping align* to \[ or $$

Tags: macros, align

I would like to remap the align* environment to `\[ \]` or `$$ $$`.

The reason is that I am using a conceal plugin that removes unnecessary stuff when viewing the code. The issue is that when it removes the `\begin{align*}`, `\end{align*}` the text inside is no longer considered as math by the concealer and it is therefore not concealed.

**Question:** How does one remap the `align*` enivronment to `$$ $$` or `\[ \]`?

Comment: I  would avoid this as it makes your document incompatible with any other, but `\def\[#1\]{\begin{align)#1\end{align}}`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I am having some issues with compiling this. In particular Runaway definition?
#1\]->\begin {align)#1\end {align}} \par \begin {document} \par \[ x \ETC.
! File ended while scanning definition of \[.
<inserted text>
                }

Comment: @MathsWizzard There's a typo, it should be `\begin{align}`, not `\begin{align)`

Comment: Excellent. That worked great. Feel free to post this as an answer.

Comment: @mbert typing on a phone while cooking dinner:-)

Comment: Hmmm.... I suspect that the correct way would be to teach the editor conceal plugin that `align*` is a math environment. XY problem maybe?

Comment: @Rmano I am using vim with https://github.com/KeitaNakamura/tex-conceal.vim if that makes  difference.

Comment: I don't use conceal but you can try to use the built-in conceal that comes with vimtex (and so you can upgrade vimtex and not stay at 1.6, which is ancient...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would avoid this as it makes your document incompatible with any other, but

```
\def\[#1\]{\begin{align}#1\end{align}}
```

Comment: Just very quickly, do you know if we can adapt this method to change $$ $$ instead? I tried \$ \$ #1 \$ \$ but didn't work.

Comment: redefining `$$` is _much_ harder and I can't recommend it at all. @MathsWizzard

Comment: No worries. Thanks for the help

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- I think you want `align*` , to avoid equation numbers.

Comment: @barbarabeeton The OP asked for align,... (I wouldn't do this at all)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle -- I see a `*`; please look again.  (I wouldn't do it either.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton ah title doesn't match the question:-) **not my fault** :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is an XY problem: if you want your editor to use the conceal option with the `align` environment, try to find a way to add this environment to the list of math-mode conceal targets without changing the document macros...

Now, in the comments you say you use `vimtex` with an external conceal plug-in. That plugin pins the vimtex version to 1.6, which is quite old. If you upgrade your vimtex to current (2.13) and use

```
set conceallevel=2
hi Conceal guibg=White guifg=Black
```

I have, in `gvim`:

[image]

For the input:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[ \alpha \setminus \beta = \gamma \]

\begin{align*}
    \alpha &= \beta \\
     \gamma &= \delta
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

(Grr... you have to `set conceallevel=0` to middle-button paste code here. That reminds me why I never use conceal...)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20557003/latex-conceal-and-weird-coloring

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I think the issue for me is that the \begin and \end align* are not hidden that way. If I add manual concel then the in-between is no longer considered math.  I think it is a more structural issue in vimtex where $$ $$ and \[ \] are treated completely differently than the align environments.

Comment: Yep, I saw it. Probably if you open an issue Lervag will answer --- he's very active in maintaining and updating vimtex-

Comment: Great, thanks for the advice.